# How to "interface" an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've got a base interface and I want my child interface to look like the base interface.
How can I do so?

```
interface BaseInterface {
  api: { [key: string]: string  };
  ui: { [key: string]: string  };
}

interface ChildInterface {
  // I want to force this interface to have the same shape as BaseInterface
  // like so :

  api: { firstName: string  };
  ui: { firstName: string  };
}
```

I tried with `type ChildInterface = BaseInterface` but I cannot manage to custom my `ChildInterface` then.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `extends` keyword.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces)

```
interface ChildInterface extends BaseInterface {
    someOtherProp:string;
}

const someItem : ChildInterface = //...
console.log(someItem.api.firstName);
console.log(someItem.someOtherProp);
```

Comment: I want to allow the developer to add a property outside the api/ui keys. The ChildInterface should be the same shape as the BaseInterface

Comment: @GreatHawkeye Could you add a description of the kind of usage that you are trying to allow for into your question please. At the moment, I am struggling to understand why the above does not satisfy your requirements.

Comment: sorry I meant "I don't* want to allow the developer to add a property outside the api/ui keys".

Comment: I've found a github issue about this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24274